# Why doesn't LINQ include a `distinct` keyword?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, keyword

NOTE: Before you read on or provide an answer, I know about `Enumerable.Distinct`, I am asking about specific language support for that method, not about the method itself.

I've always wondered why there is no `distinct` keyword in the C# LINQ keyword set so that I could write:

```
var items = distinct from x in y
            select x;
```

or

```
var items = from x in y
            select distinct x;
```

Anybody know why this wasn't included or why it would be a bad idea to include it? It just feels cumbersome to me that I have to wrap the query just to call `Distinct()`; a `distinct` keyword would feel more natural.

NOTE: I know that the `Distinct` method has overrides to provide a comparer if that is required, but a keyword that uses the default comparer would be great. I could even imagine a `distinct by` keyword combination so that a comparison operator could be provided inline to the query.

Comment: I wish we had it too.  Would be far more readible, and ime it's reasonably often used.

Comment: @qstarin: I asked the question because I needed it for the 5th time in 2 days.

Comment: Perhaps we should start a "distinct keyword for C#" facebook group. It got Betty White on SNL...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Charlie Calvert has a [blog post ("Using Distinct and Avoiding Lambdas")](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216044315/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx) discussing the issue. From the top of the post:

> 1. Most query operators such as `Select()`, `Where()` and `GroupBy()` take something called a lambda as a parameter.
>    2. Lambdas are difficult to write.
>    3. Query expressions were created in large part to allow developers to use LINQ without having to learn the complex syntax associated with lambdas.
>    4. A few query operators, such as `Distinct()`, do not take lambdas as parameters. As a result, they are easy to call.
>    5. Query expressions were therefore not created for operators such as `Distinct()` that do not take lambdas.

And also, from further down in the post:

> Query operators are method calls. In other words, there are methods in the LINQ API called `Select()`, `Group()`, `Distinct()`, etc. We don't usually call these methods directly because they take lambdas as parameters, and many people find that lambdas are hard to understand. To help developers avoid the complex task of writing lambdas, the team invented query expressions, which are a "syntactic sugar" that sit on top of lambdas.

**TL;DR:** There's no `distinct` keyword for simplicity's sake, since `distinct` does not take a lambda expression.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. That all sounds great, but it doesn't fit with HOW people use this stuff. It would be extremely useful and makes things a lot easier to read. I don't think the argument put forth by Charlie Calvert is really that strong - especially since the keyword WAS included for VB.

Comment: "We don't usually call these methods directly because they take lambdas as parameters, and many **lousy programmers who aren't worth their salt** find that lambdas are hard to understand" -- FTFY.

Comment: Totally agree with both of you. Lambdas are not that difficult, and I've been tripped up by this before -- "wait, so there's a `Distinct()` method but no `distinct` keyword?" Makes little sense to me.

Comment: "Lambdas are difficult to write."  The first time I read that article, that point made me lol hard .. and close the tab.

Comment: This seems to be the answer that has the clearest explanation relating to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Wondering out loud if, 6 years later, @Juliet et al still think expecting programmers to deal with more complex syntaxes is better than providing a simpler, easier to read syntax.

Answer (score 14):

In VB, there actually *is*.

```
Dim l = From x In {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2} Distinct Select x
```

I don't suspect there has been some active decision against `distinct` for C#, it's just has not been implemented.

Comment: Of course, I don't want to have to write all my LINQ in VB. :)

Comment: VB also has `Aggregate ... Into` in query format? Does this exist in C# too?

Comment: Not in C#. Here's a link to VB's [Aggregate clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531251%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I think it just increase the complexity of code. Instead of using fluent interface going to use sql like, makes code looks spaghetti, I think it doesn't have any advantages. I think `for` and `select` are for who knows sql but is not familiar with linq so it's easy to use them, causes to jump start in linq, but extending it is not a good way.

Comment: @Saeed: I disagree. Chaining methods together can create much harder to follow flow in some situations (especially when lambdas are included). Query syntax really helps to keep things readable in many scenarios. YOu just have to know when to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: May be your sql abilities is better than your linq, but I'm think readability of chaining is good enough, if it's hard in some case it will be more defaulter write it in sql like, All in all it depends on developer, It's my opinion.

Comment: I don't have any SQL abilities (at least, I wouldn't claim to have) - but I do feel that taking an otherwise simple LINQ query and then wrapping it with parentheses just to call `Distinct` is messy. I am just using C# language as it was intended and the lack of this keyword makes that hard to do.

Answer (score 5):

Reword:  `distinct` is a set operator... set operators don't take lambdas as parameters.  The c# team decided to give you shortcuts to methods that take lambdas, such as `Select()` and `Group()`, because they felt that lambdas can be confusing to people just starting out.  `.Distinct()` doesn't take a lambda, so is clear when you call it directly.

A good read on the subject:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216044315/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx)

Comment: That explains the distinction, but I still don't think it answers the question. `in` doesn't use a lambda. It's a convenience. The argument is flawed, especially when seeing that VB got the keyword. I think the justification is weak - that isn't criticism of your answer as you're relaying the information, but you get my point.

Comment: Reworded.  You're right, the key is that it's just a convenience.  The c# team decided there was no need for a convenience on `.Distinct()`  (Apparently the VB team disagreed)

Comment: I think they made a poor decision with regards to distinct.